# Can't scroll to every position in zoomable image

Tags: swift

i have a ViewController containing a `UIScrollView` that aligns leading,trailing and bottom to safe area and top to superview. it contains only one image that is supoosed to be as big as possible, keeping aspect ratio, fitting in the screen and be zoomable. I put the following constraints on it:
align center x and y to superview
width/height ≤ width/height of superview
keep aspect ratio

but now the image starts having it's original size(smaller than width and height of an ipad) and depending  on where i zoom in, i can't scroll to every position. How can i achieve that?
Here is my ViewController:

```
class FullscreenImageViewController: UIViewController, UIScrollViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView!
    @IBOutlet weak var fullImageView: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var closeButton: UIButton!
    var imageSource: UIImage?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        scrollView.delegate = self
        fullImageView.image = imageSource
    }

    /**
     * Function used to close the presented ViewController.
     * @param sender The tapped button.
     */
    @IBAction func closeFullscreenViewController(_ sender: UIButton) {
        self.dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil)
    }

    /**
     * Function used to handle the zooming functionality. The ScrollView is given the view it should use for the zooming, in this case the imageView.
     * @param scrollView The ScrollView.
     */
    func viewForZooming(in scrollView: UIScrollView) -> UIView? {
        return fullImageView
    }
}
```

Comment: So is the zoomable image view not the same as the content of the scroll view?

Comment: what do you mean? its the only view in the scrollview

Comment: So when you say it is aligned to its superview, what superview do you mean? — Let me put it another way: what is supposed to make the scroll view scrollable? What are you doing with the _edges_ of the image view?

Answer (score 0):

> I put the following constraints on it: align center x and y to superview width/height ≤ width/height of superview keep aspect ratio

That's the problem right there. You are not doing anything to make the scroll view scrollable.

By default a scroll view is not scrollable; you need to set its content size so that it knows how much to scroll. Your scroll view has a content size of zero so it is not scrollable. It knows nothing about the zoomed size of the image, so when you zoom the image, you still can't scroll it.

You need to pin the *edges* of the image view to the scroll view, so that as the image view expands, the scroll view knows where its edges are and will let you see them.

Comment: ok, i added the 4 constraints and it works, but xcode still displays a lot of red lines. is that normal? can you tell me exactly what constraints i need on the scrollview and the imageview? i think i have too many now.

Comment: The image view needs two things: it needs to be pinned on all four sides to the scroll view, and it needs some kind of internal size determinant for both width and height. Anything else is probably superfluous. The way to know if you've got a problem is to run the app and play with it and see if you get error messages about your constraints in the console. If not, you're probably fine.